# Need suggestions for a NLP use case

Tags: python, algorithm, machine-learning, nlp, nltk

I am trying to build a web scraper that can predict the content of a given URL into multiple categories, but I am currently confused about which method is best suited for my use case. Here's the overall use case:

I want to predict a researcher's interest from their biography and categorize them into one or multiple categories based on [SDG 17 goals](https://sdgs.un.org/goals). I have three data points to work with:

1. The biography of each researcher (can be scrapped and tokenized)
2. A list of keywords that are often associated with each of the SDG categories/goals ([here's the example of said keywords](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Y3k06f30j-mXUx1Qo-jelOJCWRiGvJOwRDA0Mwd7rIg/edit#gid=0))
3. Hundreds of categorizations that are done manually by students in the form of binary data ([here's the example of said data](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Y3k06f30j-mXUx1Qo-jelOJCWRiGvJOwRDA0Mwd7rIg/edit#gid=1745344524))

So far, we have students that read each researcher's biography and decide which SDG category/goal each researcher belongs to. One research can belong to one or more SDG categories. We usually categorize it based on how often SDG keywords listed in our database are present in each researcher's bio.

I have looked up online machine learning models for NLP but couldn't decide on which method would work best with my use case. Any suggestions and references would be super appreciated because I'm a bit lost here.

Answer (score 0):

The problem that you have here is a **multi-label classification** and you can solve it by applying supervised learning since you have a labelled dataset.

A labelled dataset should look something like this,

```
article 1 - sdg1, sdg2, sdg4
article 2 - sdg4
.
.
.
```

The implementation is explained in detail here - [keras - multi-label-classification](https://keras.io/examples/nlp/multi_label_classification/)

This one has plenty of things abstracted and the implementation is kept simple - [fasttext multi-label-classification](https://fasttext.cc/docs/en/supervised-tutorial.html#multi-label-classification)

Profound insights of these libraries are here,
[keras](https://kandi.openweaver.com/python/keras-team/keras) and [fasttext](https://kandi.openweaver.com/html/facebookresearch/fastText)